# How should I force WordPress to give proper name for the uploading images?

Tags: plugins, images, seo

How can I force WordPress to give a proper file name for images like "http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mona_lisa_painting.jpg" instead of "http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/28.jpg".

Do I need any plugin? Or should I not to use standard "Set featured image" upload form?

I heard that it's very important for google.
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I didn't realise that file names we updated by Wordpress? In all my installs they keep the original file name, are you using a plugin that may be renaming files?

Answer (score 0):

the best method is to rename the files *before* you upload them. WordPress doesn't rename your files from what they are already called.

However ... once you upload an image you should see this page and
- you can change the tile from 28.jpg to mona_lisa_smiles.jpg and then
- click save changes

[image: WordPress Media Library > Add Image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your idea. If I get into the Media Library and "Show" any image priperties - I can not see any option to change the file name.
But if I press the button "Attachment post URL" - the image URL becomes like http://www.musite.com/post_containing_this_image/3 (without .JPG). Is that the one?
However the page becomes wrong in this case (like some tags were lost)

Comment: @Roman ... you would need to change the filename before you upload it. For SEO purposes you can change the Title of the file something friendly

Answer (score 0):

In addition, Wordpress requires an image Title attribute, but this is something that is not nearly as important to search engines as the Alt attribute. Therefore, when you do upload the image, write something with a keyword in the Title, and then copy and paste that into the Alternate Text box as well. That will produce the best results.

Comment: A major annoyance for screen reader users. Don’t do that please.